# How to create a 180 degree camera orbit over X seconds in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, camera, rotation

I have a camera that orbits a point on the screen.  Clicking and dragging your mouse left and right will orbit around the focus point and releasing the mouse will leave the camera at that angle.

I'm trying to create a function that will orbit the camera 180 degrees, smoothly.  So for example, if the camera is behind the "player" and this function gets called, the camera will orbit to the front of the player over the course of X seconds and stop in the exact opposite position of where it started.

Here's the code I'm currently using for camera rotation based on mouse click and drag:

```
Quaternion camTurnAngle =
    Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSpeed, Vector3.up);

this.cameraOffset = camTurnAngle * this.cameraOffset;

Vector3 newPos = this.currentFocusPoint + this.cameraOffset;
transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, newPos, smoothFactor);
transform.LookAt(this.currentFocusPoint);
```

I am trying to replace this mouse-drag based camera rotate with a UI button (aka, a single function call) that will fully orbit the camera 180 degrees over a short period of time, and then it will rotate back if pressed again.  Here's an MS paint drawing just in case my explanation is confusing:

[image]

I'm not sure how do to something like this.  It sounds similar to using `Vector3.Slerp`, but I cannot find a solution that works.  I am so far from a solution that I don't really have any sensible code to post.  I'll just say that I've tried two methods so far:

1) I've tried using `transform.RotateAround`, where angle I pass in is `rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime`.  My issue is I don't know how to check for an end condition, and without one my camera will rotate forever.

2) I've tried messing with `Quaternion.Slerp`, but the results are seeing are not what I expected.

How can I achieve a smooth 180 degree camera orbit, that takes a predetermined amount of time to complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a textbook use for a [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). Basically, start a coroutine that keeps track of how much time is left in the orbit, then either updates `cameraOffset` based on the time that's left or `Time.deltaTime`, whatever is shorter.

```
private IEnumerator RotateCam(float rotateDuration)
{
    float timeLeft = rotateDuration;

    // possibly - disable control of camera here

    while (timeLeft > 0)
    {
        yield return null;

        float elapsedRotationTime = Mathf.Min(timeLeft, Time.deltaTime);
        float angleThisFrame = 180f * elapsedRotationTime / rotateDuration;

        Quaternion camTurnAngle = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleThisFrame, Vector3.up);

        this.cameraOffset = camTurnAngle * this.cameraOffset;
        transform.position = this.currentFocusPoint + this.cameraOffset;
        transform.LookAt(this.currentFocusPoint);

        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    // possibly - re-enable control of camera here
}
```

Then, when you want to begin the rotation:

```
// private Coroutine rotateCoroutine

this.rotateCoroutine = StartCoroutine(RotateCam(2f));
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the Update function and not have the overhead of a coroutine.

Comment: @Topher I would argue that using a coroutine here makes the code more readable without adding an appreciable overhead. Implementing this as a coroutine also makes it very straightforward and readable to do things like rotate the camera by 180 degrees and then do something else as soon as that completes. e.g., `IEnumerator RotThenOtherThing(){ yield return RotateCam(1f); DoOtherThing();}`

Comment: That makes sense.